# How to “nc -z <address>” with socat?

Tags: networking, netcat, socat, nc

I want to get the behavior of "nc -z *host port* ; echo $?" with socat, since my network admins have disabled netcat. The purpose is just to test that a TCP connection is open between two servers. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hi if you want check connection between server with socat try below command and refer link ..

```
CWsocat [options] <address> <address>
CWsocat -V
CWsocat -h[h[h]] | -?[?[?]]
CWfilan
CWprocan
```

try this [link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/socat) for better understanding..
there are other method to check the connectivity..

Comment: It's just socat's man page. Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since `nc -z host port` just attempt to connect without sending any data, it should be equivalent to `socat /dev/null tcp4:host:port`.

I think this can achieve your expected bahaviour with socat:

`socat /dev/null tcp4:host:port > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?`